# Customising CKEditor Toolbar

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I want to customize the toolbar of CKEditor. First, though, I want to have a complete list of available options for the toolbar. I searched for toolbar options and found the following incomplete list. Please help me to find the complete list so that I can select according to my requirements.

```
config.toolbar_MyToolbar =
[
    { name: 'document', items : [ 'NewPage','Preview' ] },
    { name: 'insert', items : [ 'Image','Flash','Table'] },
    { name: 'styles', items : [ 'Styles','Format' ] },
    { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor' ] },
    { name: 'tools', items : [ 'Maximize','-','About' ] }
];
```

Answer (score 21):

There is an explanation of the toolbar modifications [here, in the docs](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Toolbar).  Also available in their API section, [here](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.toolbar).

```
config.toolbar = 'Full';

config.toolbar_Full =
[
    { name: 'document', items : [ 'Source','-','Save','NewPage','DocProps','Preview','Print','-','Templates' ] },
    { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
    { name: 'editing', items : [ 'Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','-','SpellChecker', 'Scayt' ] },
    { name: 'forms', items : [ 'Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton', 

         'HiddenField' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','Subscript','Superscript','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote','CreateDiv','-

        ','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock','-','BidiLtr','BidiRtl' ] },
    { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor' ] },
    { name: 'insert', items : [ 'Image','Flash','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak','Iframe' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'styles', items : [ 'Styles','Format','Font','FontSize' ] },
    { name: 'colors', items : [ 'TextColor','BGColor' ] },
    { name: 'tools', items : [ 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks','-','About' ] }
];
```