# What toolbar buttons are available in CKEditor 4?

Tags: ckeditor

The CKEditor docs mention item by item toolbar configuration [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_toolbar), but where is a list of the names of the buttons in the different groups?

There is a similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463900/customising-ckeditor-toolbar), but the answer is for a previous version of CKEditor. Some of the button names do not work.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can check the [toolbar sample](https://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/old/toolbar/toolbar.html) in your CKEditor package.

There, you've got listed all buttons and all toolbar groups (since CKEditor 4 there are two ways of setting toolbar layout) that are enabled in your CKEditor build.

If you don't see a button that you remembered from CKEditor 3, check if it's available in your CKEditor package version (there are now 3 - basic, std and full). Some plugins are not included in any of these builds and you have to [create your own](http://ckeditor.com/builder).

PS. If you're using standard or basic build check `config.js` file - some buttons like Underline are removed in these presets by setting [`config.removeButtons`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-removeButtons).

Answer (score 37):

[Here](http://ckeditor.com/comment/123266#comment-123266) is a nice list of button names:

> Complete List of Toolbar Items for CKEditor

items

- "Source"
- "Save"
- "NewPage"
- "DocProps"
- "Preview"
- "Print"
- "Templates"
- "document"

items

- "Cut"
- "Copy"
- "Paste"
- "PasteText"
- "PasteFromWord"
- "Undo"
- "Redo"

items

- "Find"
- "Replace"
- "SelectAll"
- "Scayt"

items

- "Form"
- "Checkbox"
- "Radio"
- "TextField"
- "Textarea"
- "Select"
- "Button"
- "ImageButton"
- "HiddenField"

items

- "Bold"
- "Italic"
- "Underline"
- "Strike"
- "Subscript"
- "Superscript"
- "RemoveFormat"

items

- "NumberedList"
- "BulletedList"
- "Outdent"
- "Indent"
- "Blockquote"
- "CreateDiv"
- "JustifyLeft"
- "JustifyCenter"
- "JustifyRight"
- "JustifyBlock"
- "BidiLtr"
- "BidiRtl"

items

- "Link"
- "Unlink"
- "Anchor"

items

- "CreatePlaceholder"
- "Image"
- "Flash"
- "Table"
- "HorizontalRule"
- "Smiley"
- "SpecialChar"
- "PageBreak"
- "Iframe"
- "InsertPre"

items

- "Styles"
- "Format"
- "Font"
- "FontSize"

items

- "TextColor"
- "BGColor"

items

- "UIColor"
- "Maximize"
- "ShowBlocks"

items

- "button1"
- "button2"
- "button3"
- "oembed"
- "MediaEmbed"

items

- "About"

Comment: There is one new item in full toolbar named CopyFormatting. It is placed next to RemoveFormat button.

Comment: @EduardVoid, oh feel free to update the answer. I haven't touched CK in years!

Answer (score 7):

Simply generate your own configaration in visual [**CKEditor Toolbar Configurator**](http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/toolbarconfigurator/index.html#basic)

*Generated an example:*

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
  config.toolbarGroups = [
    { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
    { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker', 'editing' ] },
    { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
    { name: 'forms', groups: [ 'forms' ] },
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi', 'paragraph' ] },
    { name: 'links', groups: [ 'links' ] },
    { name: 'insert', groups: [ 'insert' ] },
    { name: 'styles', groups: [ 'styles' ] },
    { name: 'colors', groups: [ 'colors' ] },
    { name: 'tools', groups: [ 'tools' ] },
    { name: 'others', groups: [ 'others' ] },
    { name: 'about', groups: [ 'about' ] }
  ];

  config.removeButtons = 'Form,Radio,TextField,Textarea,Select,Button,ImageButton,HiddenField,BidiLtr,BidiRtl,Language,Styles,Font,Smiley,CreateDiv,Checkbox,Scayt,NewPage,About';
};
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting the link ... I just could not find that one.

Answer (score 3):

Underline option is available, but by default it's not visible. You need to remove it from below line in config.js file.

```
config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';
```