# CKEditor inline rearrange auto-generated toolbar

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, inline, toolbar, contenteditable

I have an inline content editor by using the contenteditable attribute.
What I want is to rearrange the default auto-generated toolbar.
The usual method is to create something like:

```
config.toolbar = [
{ name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ], items: [ 'Source', '-', 'Templates' ] },
{ name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ], items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ] },
{ name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ], items: [ 'Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'Scayt' ] },
{ name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ], items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] },
'/',
{ name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ], items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl' ] },
{ name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' ] },
{ name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe' ] },
'/',
{ name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
{ name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] },
{ name: 'tools', items: [ 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks' ] },
{ name: 'others', items: [ '-' ] },
];
```

in the config.js.

The problem is that I don't know where to find the already auto-generated toolbar so as to change it the way I want. So I don't know what are the names used in the toolbar and therefore I can't make it how I want.

(the code used above is not the one I want obviously..)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [Setting Configuration guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration)? You can either set toolbar in the `config.js` file which will be loaded while initializing editor or directly in `CKEDITOR.inline`, but to use this method you need to disable automatic editors creation:

```
// We need to turn off the automatic editor creation first.
CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;

var editor = CKEDITOR.inline( 'editable', {
    toolbar: [ ... ]
} );
```

If you don't know button names, then check out this question: [What toolbar buttons are available in CKEditor 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828383/what-toolbar-buttons-are-available-in-ckeditor-4/13835820#13835820)

Note: instead of rearranging entire toolbar, you can just rearrange groups of buttons – read more in the [Toolbar Customization guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_toolbar-section-1).

Comment: Well, I've already known these things as you can see from the code I've pasted above. And I've already tried to use the config.js. In fact this is what I'm going to use to rearrange the toolbar or the toolbarGroups.
What I'm asking is if I can find the auto-generated code somewhere. Where is the original toolbar populated when it is left in default mode as downloaded from the site? (custom download from builder)

Comment: Check out the last sentence in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help but you seem to not understand. I know this stuff. What I want is to learn where the autogenerated code is put when you make an inline editor. So that I can take the config from there and alter it the way I want. I don't want to make a guess on what buttons I may or may not use. It must auto-build somewhere. That's what I'm looking for!

Comment: I'm still not sure what do you mean (perhaps because you haven't explained what are you trying to do), but is [this function](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/toolbar/plugin.js#L404) clarifying anything? Note - you wrote - *"So I don't know what are the names used in the toolbar and therefore I can't make it how I want."* - but configuration options exist to "make it how you want", not internals.

Comment: There is a great feature at http://ckeditor.com/builder which allows you to build your own version of ckeditor.
And after your changes when you try your download everything is set by default to show exactly what you've downloaded.
But, at a predefined order. I wanted to change that order.
So I hoped that something like the array in config.toolbar existed in order to just take it and change it simply.
I couldn't find such a thing, and that's what I was asking in the first place. Sorry if I was saying it wrong or something. If I had more reputation I would attach photos..

Comment: I did what I wanted to do eventually, of course by using the config.toolbar. I just hoped it would be easier than guessing names and searching for what plugins I once installed.
Thanks anyway for you help! :)

Comment: Hmm... As I predicted, the link in the last paragraph of my answer is the best resource. That sample was created exactly for this purpose - checking what's the generated toolbar groups or toolbar layout, to be able to copy it and change it manually. There's no API which allows to modify current layout during runtime. Anyway, I'm glad you solved your problem :).