# How to know all the plugin names in CKEditor?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

Where can I view the names of all the plugins that are available in the CKEditor. I have downloaded the complete package of CKEditor and I want to remove some default plugins such as Indent, Text Direction from RTL, Text Direction from LTR and more. Where will be all the names for these plugins available so that I can disable them using this syntax,

```
config.removePlugins = 'forms,elementspath';
```

Comment: http://ckeditor.com/addons/accessibility

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The easiest way is by checking this variable:

```
CKEDITOR.config.plugins;
```

For example full build contains these plugins:

```
"dialogui,dialog,a11yhelp,about,basicstyles,bidi,blockquote,clipboard," +
"button,panelbutton,panel,floatpanel,colorbutton,colordialog,menu," +
"contextmenu,dialogadvtab,div,elementspath,enterkey,entities,popup," +
"filebrowser,find,fakeobjects,flash,floatingspace,listblock,richcombo," +
"font,format,forms,horizontalrule,htmlwriter,iframe,image,indent," +
"indentblock,indentlist,justify,link,list,liststyle,magicline," +
"maximize,newpage,pagebreak,pastefromword,pastetext,preview,print," +
"removeformat,resize,save,menubutton,scayt,selectall,showblocks," +
"showborders,smiley,sourcearea,specialchar,stylescombo,tab,table," +
"tabletools,templates,toolbar,undo,wsc,wysiwygarea"
```

You can also check which buttons are available: [What toolbar buttons are available in CKEditor 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828383/what-toolbar-buttons-are-available-in-ckeditor-4/13835820#13835820)

Comment: Is there something similar for buttons?

Comment: As late as this information may come, one can find a list of buttons here: https://ckeditor.com/old/forums/CKEditor/Complete-list-of-toolbar-items#comment-123266

Answer (score 2):

See the Toolbar Configurator to customize  http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/toolbarconfigurator/index.html#basic

Regards, Nicholls