# not able to add docprops plugin to ckeditor toolbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I am using ckeditor 4.3.4 . i have downloaded plugin called docprops with dependencies.

but when i add to toolbar , the button is not displaying.

i use toolbar like this

```
config.toolbar = [
{ name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ], items: [ 'Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates' ] },
{ name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ], items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ] },
{ name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ], items: [ 'Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'Scayt' ] },
{ name: 'forms', items: [ 'Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton', 'HiddenField' ] },
'/',
{ name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ], items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] },
{ name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ], items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl', 'Language' ] },
{ name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' ] },
{ name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe' ] },
'/',
{ name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
{ name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] },
{ name: 'tools', items: [ 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks' ] },
{ name: 'others', items: [ '-' ] },
{ name: 'about', items: [ 'About' ] },
{ name: 'ficplugin', items: ['ficFieldFunctions','base64image'] },
{ name: 'ficplugin1', items: ['docprops'] }
```

];

but if i don't use this configuration then it is coming but i am not able to add my extra plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button's name is `'DocProps'`, not `'docprops'`.

See also: [What toolbar buttons are available in CKEditor 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828383/what-toolbar-buttons-are-available-in-ckeditor-4/13835820#13835820)