# CKEDITOR StrikeThrough button on toolbar not appearing

Tags: ckeditor, toolbar

I have access to the [StrikeThrough] button when `config.toolbar=null` which causes the full toolbar to be created.  But when I attempt to create a custom, more limited toolbar, I'm unable to get StrikeThrough button to appear there.

```
CKEDITOR.config.toolbar_Foo = [[ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'StrikeThrough' ] ] 
CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = 'Foo';
```

Only Bold and Italic appear on the toolbar.

What's my error? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

LOL. I tried StrikeThru, strikeThrough, strikeThru, strikethru, and strikethrough, thinking that it might be a case or spelling issue. It's simply "Strike".

Comment: See [What toolbar buttons are available in CKEditor 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828383/what-toolbar-buttons-are-available-in-ckeditor-4/13835820#13835820) if you ever have a problem with button names again.

Comment: Seems to be longer working with 4.7.x (tested 4.7.2 and 4.7.3) releases? I use `Strike` in my toolbar.